# Kill the process with processId

Tags: qt, kill-process, qprocess

I have a Q_Object class.
In this class, I want to start and stop a process with the send and stop function

My send function is working fine and when I click it my process is running but when I click on the stop function it is not working  because I do not have access to the processId
How can I fix this problem??

```
class Simulator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Simulator(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Simulator();
    EnvHandler *envHandler = new EnvHandler;

signals:


public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void send();
    Q_INVOKABLE void stop();
private:
    QProcess *m_process;
    qint64 pId;

};
```

```
#include "Simulator.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <fstream>


Simulator::Simulator(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent} , m_process(new QProcess(this))
{


}


void Simulator::send()
{
    QString path = envHandler->env_MERSAD_HOME() +"/Bin/Module/DataGenerator";
    m_process->startDetached(path);
     pId = m_process->processId();
}

void Simulator::stop()
{
   
    QString command = "kill -9 " + QString::number(pId);
    m_process->execute(command);
}



Simulator::~Simulator()
{

}
```

Comment: Can't you use [`kill`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#kill) on the QProcess `m_process`?

Comment: @iam_peter can use but when call stop function do not kill the process

Comment: You get the pId by passing it as a parameter into startDetached. See the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached).

Comment: @hossein Please remember that StackOverflow is not a help desk, nor a forum. Some questions get answers even **years** after being asked, so: 1. you cannot expect an answer just *one hour* after posting your question; 2. comments should only be used to discuss or expand questions/answers, so please avoid any attempt to "bump" with unnecessary comments. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to retrieve the process ID after the process is detached. You can change the way you are calling startDetached so that it provides you the ID. Then you should be able to kill it.

```
void Simulator::send()
{
    QString path = envHandler->env_MERSAD_HOME() +"/Bin/Module/DataGenerator";
    m_process->setProgram(path);
    m_process->startDetached(&pId);
}
```

Comment: thanks but now i can not kill my process !!!!!!